# Docker-Composeを用いたWebアプリケーションDjangoとアクセス解析ツールMatomoの構築方法について

Tags: docker, django, docker-compose

Docker-Composeを用いたWebアプリケーションDjangoとアクセス解析ツールMatomoの構築方法についてわからなかったので質問させてください。

アクセス解析ツールMatomoはDocker-Composeを用いて構築できるそうです。
https://mebee.info/2020/07/14/post-13414/

また、DjangoもDocker-Composeを用いて構築できるそうです。
http://docs.docker.jp/compose/django.html

このとき、Docker-Composeを用いたWebアプリケーションDjangoとアクセス解析ツールMatomoの構築する仕方がわかりませんでした。MatomoでDjangoのWebアプリケーションの訪問者数を確認できるようにしたいです。

どなたかご教示頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: こことか参考になりそうです。https://github.com/wmapst/wmap_infrastructure_matomo/blob/master/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Docker や Docker Compose 自体の使い方は理解していますか？もしわからないのであればそれらの基礎を学ぶことから始める必要があると思います。 / あなたの理解度は第三者からはわからないので、「ここまではできた」「この部分が分からない」のようにもう少し具体的な説明があると回答が付きやすくなると思います。